# Should An Original Post Include an Attempt to Solve?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I saw a comment recently indicating that a user down voted a question because the posting user did not include a description - in either writing or code - of his or her attempt to solve the issue about which he or she asked. This struck me as a bit strange, particularly as the question was a simple "how to" question (primitive data type conversion). Too, the question had a plain answer.

Of course, the answer to such a question is simple, often times the question receiving "check out the documentation" answers and a link to the relevant documentation, etc.

*I understand that users should not expect the StackOverflow community to solve problems which the user has not attempted to solve*. So, if a question is not in the "solve this large problem for me because I am too lazy" genre, does the question warrant down voting if it does not include an attempt to answer?

Comment: If you feel that the answer to the question is, "Go read the documentation" the the question almost certainly "does not show any research effort" which is listed as one of the metrics for downvoting a question.

Comment: It **always** should have an attempt at solving the problem or show research effort and what they do/do not understand of the problem. This does two things: 1) shows us that you don't expect us to write your app, 2) keeps us from going over possibilities that the OP has already tried eliminating the wasting of everyone's time.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks for clarifying your comment, i.e. adding to what you had originally written. I think the second point you make is particularly valid. I had another "idea" in conjunction with yours, as well: (3) posting an attempt may also reveal a flaw in the user's understanding of a process.

Comment: This close reason seems to guide us to close when no attempt exists: "Needs debugging details
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

An attempted solution is not a goal. It's a tool to help us better understand where the original poster is stuck by learning what have they tried. Questions should be judged based on their usefulness. Not based on how "deserving" someone is to get an answer.

I do not close questions that don't show attempted solutions unless those solutions would clarify them and they are otherwise unclear. To make my point:

#### Let's name successful good questions that didn't do this, from this month's top list.

- [Is recursion a feature in and of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584692/is-recursion-a-feature-in-and-of-itself)
- [Does Git warn me if a shorthand commit ID can refer to 2 different commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492381/does-git-warn-me-if-a-shorthand-commit-id-can-refer-to-2-different-commits)
- [Does Garbage Collector run on Enum type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525768/does-garbage-collector-run-on-enum-type)
- [Strange "->* []" expression in C++ source code of cpp.react library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619152/strange-expression-in-c-source-code-of-cpp-react-library)
- [Why do two strings separated by space concatenate in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811203/why-do-two-strings-separated-by-space-concatenate-in-ruby)

Are 5 recent examples I ran in to by clicking on random questions in the month's top list.

---

So, to conclude:

Attempted solutions are good, because they help clarify what is being asked and guide answers, but they are not always applicable.

Comment: "they are not always applicable" but almost always are. Far too often they aren't included when they are needed. The few special cases when they aren't included and aren't needed are negligible.

Comment: What this answer says to me is "StackOVerflow.com" in your opinion is a free coding service

Comment: Please elaborate how this does not conflict with the close reason:
 "Needs debugging details -
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."

Answer (score 0):

## Yes.

"How to" can be closed and -1'd for a lot for reasons in most cases (at least -1 for no effort (This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful), but probably comes with other problems that would justify closing like unclear, recommending tool…, duplicate, and too broad).

*We're a Q&A site, not a help or tutorial site.*

Comment: A lack of effort is *definitely* a reason to downvote. But it is not *necessarily* a reason to close. That has to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis. If it is a legitimate, answerable question, then it deserves to be open, regardless of the amount of work the asker put into solving the problem herself.

Comment: @Cody "but ***probably*** comes with other problems that would justify closing"