# Is a question that shows no attempt to solve a problem considered 'unclear'?

Tags: discussion, questions, unclear

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333998/remove-entire-line-if-it-does-not-contain-a-phrase) question yesterday:

> I have string that looks like the following, and I would like to go through and delete lines that don't contain the tags _JJ or _NN.
>
> input:
>
> ```
> Hello_NN
> and_CC
> Happy_JJ
> Birthday_NN
> to_TO
> me_NN
> !_!
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> Hello_NN
> Happy_JJ
> Birthday_NN
> me_NN
> ```

This question could have been improved upon by including an attempt to solve but I don't believe something like that is [required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256682/should-an-original-post-include-an-attempt-to-solve).

This question has been closed as unclear what they were asking, but I did not think it was unclear at all. And I don't believe I'm alone, as someone else was able to give an answer to the problem.

I can see why this may have been 'too broad' as it is a problem that can be approached from multiple ways, but why is it *unclear*?

Comment: "Well, without seeing what you've attempted already, it's hard to explain in detail".  Any answer that starts with that phrase is an answer that is just *guessing* at the OP's hang-up.  Guesses are not answers.

Comment: Could it be that most of the close votes were cast before the question was edited?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I suppose that's possible, but I would hope those votes might have to be recast for an edit. What if it was the OP who edited the question to make it better?

Comment: per my reading, it's not even a question. It's a plain statement: "I would like to go through and delete lines that don't contain the tags _JJ or _NN". If I would VtC it, I'd probably also pick "unclear what you're **asking**" (though I would rather edit instead, because missing question seems to be rather straightforward to guess)

Comment: @gnat I see where you're coming from, but I think it's pretty clear when someone says "I would like to do this" that they're having trouble with it. It's the same reason I hate comments that say "Yes there is." When someone says "Is there any way to do this?" I hope we have enough common sense to see past that.

Comment: @McAdam331 given that asker didn't put an effort to even type the question, I find it rather fair that close voters preferred to abstain of effort to decipher it either. What surprises me here is that even those who put their effort into answering (which apparently includes effort to read and decode) didn't edit the question. There are even [badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272535/839601 "Explainer - Refiner - Illuminator") for that...

Comment: @gnat I did both.

Comment: I see, thanks. Your edit in [rev 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27333998/revisions) could be part of the problem. Original wording had something that could make a question: "How would I go around to deleting blah blah", its removal could lead to voters choosing "unclear". If you would add straight question like "How to do this?" things could go differently

Comment: We come across these types of questions all the time. I think they should belong somewhere else in stack exchange... Perhaps we need a better reason for closing to choose from. Straight up questions like this with no code attempt read as if from a textbook or assignment for programming 101. In fact we infer that the OP does not yet understand basic programming concepts and we cannot provide an adequately detailed answer because there is a character limit on posts... I can't even infer the language that they would prefer the solution in, though I guess the tags should provide that.